# Launch visual flow from process builder tu update same record

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a process builder to call a visual flow which collect some data from custom metadata based on information in different objects. After get this data, I need to update the record which fired the process builder but I get the below error:

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out' error

I tried to revolve this with a wait element in the visual flow but the error still continues.

The process builder is launched only when the record is new. Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: the error message tells you that a callout is being done somewhere as a side effect of some DML that your PB or VisualFlow does. You need to do callouts before DML (or do the callouts in an asynchronous transaction)

Comment: Add the wait on the process builder. Try 0 hours as a scheduled action instead of immediate. Custom metadata types are different and if your initial record hasnt saved yet this makes sense.